# Trying to display list of items from a field type on a page template in Drupal 7 without using Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm about at my wit's end on this one so I'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction. I have a content type called portfolio_item with a text field called field_portfolio_description. I am trying to print a list of every value that exists for that field without using Views. This is the preprocess_page function I have so far in my template.php file:

```
function blocks_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  $node = menu_get_object();
  if ($node->type == 'portfolio_item') {
    $portfolios = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_portfolio_description');
    $items = array();
    foreach ($portfolios as $folio) {
      $items['data'] = $folio['value'];
    }
    $vars['description'] = theme('item_list', array('items' => $items));
  }
}
```

Finally I am trying to call it on my page template with the following:

```
<?php print render($description); ?>
```

I've tried several different variations to no avail. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Update: alright I'm finally getting some debugging results. I'm getting the following error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in blocks_preprocess_page() (line 24 of /sites/all/themes/blocks/template.php), and this is line 24:

```
if ($node->type == 'portfolio_item') {
```

portfolio_item is the machine name of the content type so that is not the issue.

Update 2: Alright so I've stripped down the function all the way to the $node = menu_get_object(); line and did a var_dump (dpm wasn't working) and discovered that the non-object error resulted in the fact that portfolio_item wasn't present in the output when visiting a page. The only time portfolio_item is present is when visiting an actual portfolio item.

It would appear therefor that I'm going about this in the completely wrong way. It also seems that Views will not let me display a simple list of the items in that field.

I will probably revisit this later on, and if I ever find a solution I'll be sure to post the final code. Again if anyone else has ideas I'm open to try them. Thanks again to those who chimed in.

Comment: Obvious things to check...1. Your theme is called "blocks" (as in the info file is called `blocks.info`. 2. You've cleared the caches since implementing the hook. 3. You've verified that the `if` condition is being entered so you know the code _should_ be firing. 4. The node in question 100% definitely has data for that field. As an aside, get the Devel module and use the `dpm()` function to inspect your variables (it will tell you immediately whether something's missing)

Comment: @clive yes I've checked all of those things to make sure I didn't miss anything obvious. I do have the Devel module installed and I've been messing around with the dpm function to try and narrow down where the issue lies. I'm going to keep at it, I'm sure I'm close now and there's just one little thing I'm missing. Thank you for the response, and if you have any more ideas I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$node = menu_get_object();
if ($node->type == 'portfolio_item') {
  $portfolios = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_portfolio_description');
  $vars['description'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'item_list',
    '#items' => $portfolios
  );
}
```

In order to use the render function, you must pass it a render array.  The field_get_items function already returns an array or renderable elements.  Then all you have to do is pass its  return value inside of a properly structured render array.  The render function will then convert it to markup.

```
theme('item_list', array('items' => $items));
```

This theme function call returns markup, so you do not need to pass it through the render function.  The other reason why your code does not work is because you are resetting the $items['data'] value on every iteration

```
$items['data'] = $folio['value'];
```

Should be

```
$items['data'][] = $folio['value'];
```

The solution above should do it for you and it is the Drupal 7 way of rendering markup

See:  Render Arrays in Drupal 7 - http://drupal.org/node/930760

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I went ahead and tried your version of the function but I'm still not getting anything even after clearing the cache. @clive mentioned trying dpm() to try and narrow down the problem so I'm going to see if I can find exactly where the issue is. If you have any other ideas I'm all ears. Thanks again.

Comment: Give it a shot from "blocks_preprocess_node".  You will then need to update the node.tpl.php file.

Answer (score 0):

`hook_preprocess_page()` already gets a node object; there isn't the need to load it again. Your code is then using just one of the values contained in the text field, even if it loops through the array content, as it saves the values always in `$items['data']`.

The code you should write is similar to the following one.

```
function blocks_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  $items = array();

  if (!empty($vars['node']) && $vars['node']->type == 'portfolio_item') {
    $portfolios = field_get_items('node', $vars['node'], 'field_portfolio_description');
    foreach ($portfolios as $folio) {
      $items[] = $folio['value'];
    }

    $vars['description'] = theme('item_list', array('items' => $items));
  }
}
```

You can safely pass a string to `render()`, as it first checks the datatype of the argument it gets.

```
function render(&$element) {
  if (is_array($element)) {
    show($element);
    return drupal_render($element);
  }
  else {
    // Safe-guard for inappropriate use of render() on flat variables: return
    // the variable as-is.
    return $element;
  }
}
```